# How to crawl 'ETFdb.com' Data series

Tags: python

```
url = "https://etfdb.com/etf/SPY"
html = requests.get(url).text

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

dataSeries = soup.find_all('div', attrs={ 'data-series': True })

print(dataSeries)

print(dataSeries.text)
```

dataSeries show some list of numbers, but dataSeries.text didnt show

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYPJ7.png)

Comment: Could you provide more info on the current problem ? Currently, what is not working ?

Comment: What is the question? What is not working?

Comment: Print(DataSeries) Shows below

[<div data-series="[[1303084800000, 1.4655190917], [1303171200000, -1.9455978662], [1303257600000, -1.18851944075], [1303344000000, 2.26941636295], [1303430400000, 0.0], [1303689600000, -1.2979325850999999], [1303776000000, -0.106875572], [1303862400000, -0.3639436083], [1303948800000, 2.77420051715], [1304035200000, 0.0612672282], [1304294400000, -0.852886975], [1304380800000, -0.15665575425], [1304467200000, 1.7241911033], [1304553600000, -1.1125759095], [1304640000000, -1.7239931004000002], [1649980800000, 0.0]]]" id="aumcontainer"></div>]

Comment: but Print(DataSeries.Text) show none